# Member function pointer as template arguement failed on inherited member functions, how and why?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, member-functions

As the following example `v0::test()`, we want to write a template function to invoke all `class C`'s member funtions using `class C`'s member function pointer as template arguement, but this way failed on inherited member functions from parients. To ease those failures, we have to add an overload for every base class(see `v1::test()`), and in some more complicated case its even difficult to write the base class name such as `std:tuple`, or change the whole function design to `v2...v4`.
Is there any better way?

```cpp
struct A {
  void fa() {}
};
struct B : A {
  void fb() {}
};
struct C : B {
  void fc() {}
};

namespace v0 {
using c_mem_fn = void (C::*)();
template <c_mem_fn fn>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

void test() {
  C cc;
  C* c = &cc;
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fc>(c);
  //  invoke_c_mem_fn<&B::fb>(c); // compile error
  //  invoke_c_mem_fn<&A::fa>(c); // compile error
  //  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fb>(c); // compile error
  //  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fa>(c); // compile error
}
} // namespace v0

namespace v1 {
using c_mem_fn = void (C::*)();
template <c_mem_fn fn>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

using b_mem_fn = void (B::*)();
template <b_mem_fn fn>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

template <void (A::*fn)()>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

void test() {
  C cc;
  C* c = &cc;
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fc>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&B::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&A::fa>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fa>(c);
}
} // namespace v1

namespace v2 {
template <typename Fn, Fn fn>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

void test() {
  C cc;
  C* c = &cc;
  invoke_c_mem_fn<decltype(&C::fc), &C::fc>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<decltype(&B::fb), &B::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<decltype(&A::fa), &A::fa>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<decltype(&C::fb), &C::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<decltype(&C::fa), &C::fa>(c);
}
} // namespace v2

namespace v3 {
template <typename Fn>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(Fn fn, C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

void test() {
  C cc;
  C* c = &cc;
  invoke_c_mem_fn(&C::fc, c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn(&B::fb, c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn(&A::fa, c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn(&C::fb, c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn(&C::fa, c);
}
} // namespace v3

namespace v4 {
template <typename X, void (X::*fn)()>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}

void test() {
  C cc;
  C* c = &cc;
  invoke_c_mem_fn<C, &C::fc>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<B, &B::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<A, &A::fa>(c);
  //  invoke_c_mem_fn<C, &C::fb>(c); // compiler error
  //  invoke_c_mem_fn<C, &C::fa>(c); // compiler error
  invoke_c_mem_fn<B, &C::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<A, &C::fa>(c);
}
} // namespace v4

int main() {
  v1::test();
  v2::test();
  v3::test();
  v4::test();
}
```

Comment: What compile errors do you get?

Comment: `&B::fb` has type `void (B::*)()`, not `void (C::*)()`. These pointer types are not related.

Comment: @VTT you're right, but `class C` can also call the inherited member functions `void (B::*)()`. 
and I wonder there's an way call like ：`template <auto fn> void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) { (c->*fn)(); }`

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question, which is preferable to editing your question with the answer. (One advantage of answering is that this question could be taken off the unanswered question list. Then people going through that list would not waste their time reading the question only to find out at the very end that no answer is being sought anymore.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the c++17 syntax `template <auto>`  in `v5::test()`, this solved my problem, thanks you all for reading and answering.

```cpp
namespace v5 {
template <auto fn>
void invoke_c_mem_fn(C* c) {
  (c->*fn)();
}
void test() {
  C cc;
  C* c = &cc;
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fc>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&B::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&A::fa>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fb>(c);
  invoke_c_mem_fn<&C::fa>(c);
}
} // namespace v5
```